# The flip-card in my Godox 685 fell out; what to do?

Tags: flash, repair, godox

I was shooting some runway stuff last week and the built-in bounce flip-card came out completely. I tried re-inserting it during the show but it only crimped at the edges.

Do I need to take the flash head apart to re-insert? Or would it be better to get an accessory bounce card?

BTW, the 14mm diffuser still functions normally i.e. AE with Nikon D lenses.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same with my V860, but managed to get it back in quite easily.

I took the 14 mm diffuser half out, and then inserted the bounce card behind it starting with one side, so a little tilted. Then pressed the side that was in already firmly against the edge and gently pushed the other side in too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd just get a cheap bounce reflector that attaches to the top of the flash head with an elastic band. In fact, that's what I often use with my camera mounted speedlights or off-camera speedlights in 'run-and-gun' situations, even though the pull-out bounce cards on my flashes are all intact.

The one I use the most is the smaller of the two that came in [this 2-piece kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LZRBOME) with one small and one larger reflector. I paid about $15 for both. The larger one is a little unwieldy for on-camera use but does nicely for quick off-camera usage. I can set the flash mounted on the supplied "foot" on a table and aim it at my subject to get off axis light, shoot, and then grab the flash and move on in a matter of seconds.

[image]

If you don't want the larger one, you can find kits with two of the smaller example for about $10.

Most of the smaller ones have a white side and a silver side. The elastic can be easily flipped to either side to use whichever side you want.

[image]

Comment: Yeah...this is what I was thinking also. I was just hoping there would be  a simple way of getting the card back in.